# Render Line From Rectangles

Tags: c#, line, overlapping, bresenham

I've currently implemented the Bresenham line algorithm for a tile based world editor I'm developing. For <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> functionality, I would like to render a line based off the selection rectangle from a tileset. This is simple, as I can just find the points on the line from `point1` to `point2` using the algorithm and draw the selection at each point.

The issue with this is that the points overlap when the selection rectangle is larger than one tile. The result is as seen below.

[image: Current]

My question is given all the points on a line, and the selection size, how can I get a result like this? Note that I want to stop drawing the selection once it goes past `point2`.

[image: Desired]

Here's what I have currently for rendering a line without respect to the selection size.

```
void renderPoint(Point point, bool invalidate = false)
{
    Rectangle selection = world.SelectionRectangle;

    int width = selection.Width / world.Settings.TileSize.Width,
        height = selection.Height / world.Settings.TileSize.Height,
        offsetX = (int)Math.Floor((float)width / 2),
        offsetY = (int)Math.Floor((float)height / 2);

    for (int x = point.X, sx = 0; x < point.X + width; x++, sx++)
    {
        for (int y = point.Y, sy = 0; y < point.Y + height; y++, sy++)
        {
            Point change = new Point(x - offsetX, y - offsetY);

            if (!changesUndo.ContainsKey(change))
                changesUndo[change] = world.GetTile(change);

            WorldTile tile = new WorldTile(selection.X + (sx * world.Settings.TileSize.Width), selection.Y + (sy * world.Settings.TileSize.Height), 0);

            world.SetTile(change.X, change.Y, tile);

            changesRedo[change] = tile;
        }
    }

    lastRenderedPoint = point;

    if (invalidate)
        world.InvalidateCanvas();
}

void renderLine(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    List<Point> points = pointsOnLine(p1, p2);

    for (int i = 0; i < points.Count; i++)
        renderPoint(points[i], i == points.Count - 1);
}
```

Leave a comment if you need more context of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the points are rendered with Bresenham, then you have to skip every 'n-1' out of 'n' points, where 'n' is the selection size in the major direction of the line (i.e. if it's a mostly horizontal line, the width).

Something like this? :

```
void renderLine(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    List<Point> points = pointsOnLine(p1, p2);

    int dx = Abs(p2.x - p1.x);
    int dy = Abs(p2.y - p1.y);

    Rectangle selection = world.SelectionRectangle;

    int incr = selection.Width / world.Settings.TileSize.Width;
    if(dy > dx)
    {
        incr = selection.Height / world.Settings.TileSize.Height;
    }

    int lastPoint = (points.Count-1) / incr;
    lastPoint *= incr;

    for (int i = 0; i <= lastPoint; i+=incr)
        renderPoint(points[i], i == lastPoint);
}
```

Comment: That's genius! I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks a lot Jason! For future reference however, `lastPoint` should be `(points.Count - 1) / incr`, otherwise you reach outside the points list. Thanks again :)

Comment: Noted - I'll adjust the answer for reference.